# SerializationException in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, generics, serialization

I want to serialize a class, Product, and save all the `List<Product>` in a txt. I´m using validation rules to validate the price in the interface.

When I call the serialize method I´m getting a `SerializationException`, the type `System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule` is not mark as serializable.

Pl How can I fix it? Thnks.

My Code:

In Product.cs

```
    [Serializable()]
    public class Product : ValidationRule
    {
        protected float _price;

        public float Price
        {
            get;set;                
        }

        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            bool status = float.TryParse(value.ToString(), out this._price);
            return status ? ValidationResult.ValidResult
                          : new ValidationResult(false, "Message");
        }
    }
```

In the MainWindows.xaml.cs:

```
        private List<Product> _products;
        private string _directory;
        private BinaryFormatter formatter;

        // Other methods, constructors
        InsertProduct(new Product(tb_price.Text));

        // Some code

        public void Serializar()
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_directory, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, (List<Product>)_products);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The error quite clearly states that `System.Windows.Controls.ValidationRule` is not serializable, so you can't serialize it. Don't subclass `ValidationRule`, use composition.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your Validate property with

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.IgnoreDataMember]
```